# Can't get rid of Customer Portal dependency in Managed package

Tags: managed-package, customer-portal, isv, upload

I have a managed package which once use Customer Portal features. I think I removed them all (at least I can't find them) but whenevery I try to upload a new major or patch release the Customer Portal requirement checkbox is checked and cannot be unchecked.

1. Where or how can I see what components are the cause for this requirement.
2. Can it be that the requirement persists even without any causes?
3. In case of 2) how can I get rid of it, especially in a world where nobody wants portals anymore ;-)

**EDIT: The is no explicit dependancy listed on the `View Dependency` Page.**

Comment: Anything happening like `Site.createPortalUser` in a test method?

Answer (score 1):

Did you click on the View Dependencies button in the Package page layout?

http://screencast.com/t/gSyNM3x4QSG

It should show you what components are causing feature dependencies in the package

Once you remove whatever dependency exists, it should automatically disappear -- we've accidentally created references to fields on Contact or User that are only present in a portal-enabled org and once we made those soft references, the dependency went away by itself

But it's also worth checking the Customer Portal checkbox on the Upload page to make sure it isn't turned on explicitly:

http://screencast.com/t/HMty887mNpB8

Comment: As mentioned in my question the checkbox is active and CANNOT be deactivated. Besides that the "View Dependencies" doesn't show any components referencing this feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like opening a PPortal case is your only option to troubleshoot further. :-(

Comment: Yes, I opened a case and asked for help.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Did SF support help you eventually to get rid of Portal Dependency? Or was it something you missed on your side that prevented package to let that dependency go? I'm asking cause we are trying to remove Territory Management dependency following similar to your approach and without success so far.

Comment: Wow, my memory is rusty from 5 years ago but I am fairly certain no intervention by Support was required in our case; simply removing the static references to fields/objects referenced by Customer Portal eliminated the required dependency at packaging time